# How do I get one json value value each?

Tags: php, json, parsing, jsonparser

in this my php code

```
echo $_POST[result];
```

in this my php result

```
{
"result_code":0,
"err_cd":"",
"result_msg":"",
"store_id":"M20C2685",
"status":"APPROVED",
"order_no":"600a2a044c9be",
"tr_no":725,
"tr_price":1000,
"pay_price":1000,
"approved_day":"20210122",
"approved_time":"102744",
"param1":"",
"param2":""
}
```

I want to print out each value one by one. What should I do?

Comment: Try to code something first, e.g. I suggest looking at the json api in php, for example how to iterate over elements and get/list the values. It would be nice if SO just outputs code or you but this is still pretty much a human-centric operation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) Parsing JSON

```
<?php

$str = '{"result_code":0,
"err_cd":"",
"result_msg":"",
"store_id":"M20C2685",
"status":"APPROVED",
"order_no":"600a2a044c9be",
"tr_no":725,
"tr_price":1000,
"pay_price":1000,
"approved_day":"20210122",
"approved_time":"102744",
"param1":"",
"param2":""
}';

$arr = json_decode($str, true);
echo $arr['err_cd'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $arr['result_msg'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $arr['store_id'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $arr['status'] . PHP_EOL;
// ......


// Circulates each value in the array
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    echo $item . PHP_EOL;
}
```